# Chinook Database-LINQ. I have a playlist that i need to write her name,number of songs, and her primary genre(with the most songs in that playlist.)

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities, ienumerable

I have done name and number of songs, but genre always come out as System.Collections.Generic.List

```
 var playlist = _entities.Playlists.Select(x => new PlaylistaDTO
        {
            Pesma = x.Name,
            brojPesama = x.Tracks.Count,
            Zanr = x.Tracks.OrderByDescending(y => y.Genre.Tracks.Count).Take(1).Select(z => z.Genre.Name).Distinct()//error is probably this line

        }).ToList();

        foreach (var p in playlist) {
            Console.WriteLine(p);
        }
```

And I have a class File PlaylistaDTO

```
enter code here
 public class PlaylistaDTO
{
    public string Pesma { get; set; }
    public int brojPesama { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Zanr { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Song: {Pesma}," +
               $"Number of Songs {brojPesama}" +
               $"Zanr: {Zanr}";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that "System.Collections.Generic.List" because of the way your define Zanr in PlaylistDTO.   Not sure what your Zanr contains, but you might want to.ToString() it.

Assuming you have an entity Tracks and an entity Playlists, the program below should work for you:

```
    var playlists = new List<Playlist>();
    playlists.Add(new Playlist() { Name = "Playlist1", TrackName = "Track1" });
    playlists.Add(new Playlist() { Name = "Playlist1", TrackName = "Track2" });
    playlists.Add(new Playlist() { Name = "Playlist1", TrackName = "Track3" });
    var tracks = new List<Track>();
    tracks.Add(new Track() { TrackName = "Track1", Genre = "Genre1" });
    tracks.Add(new Track() { TrackName = "Track2", Genre = "Genre2" });
    tracks.Add(new Track() { TrackName = "Track3", Genre = "Genre2" });


    var playlist = playlists
        .Join(tracks, t => t.TrackName, p => p.TrackName, (p, t) => new { p, t})
        .GroupBy(x => x.p.Name)
        .Select(x => new PlaylistaDTO
        {
            Pesma = x.Key,
            brojPesama = x.Count(),
            Zanr = x.GroupBy(y => y.t.Genre).Select(y => new { Genre = y.Key, Count = y.Count() }).OrderByDescending(y => y.Count).FirstOrDefault().Genre
        })
        .ToList();

    foreach (var p in playlist)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(p.ToString());
    }
}
public class PlaylistaDTO
{
    public string Pesma { get; set; }
    public int brojPesama { get; set; }
    public string Zanr { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Song: {Pesma}," +
               $"Number of Songs {brojPesama}," +
               $"Zanr: {Zanr}";
    }
}
public class Playlist
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string TrackName { get; set; }
}
public class Track
{
    public string TrackName { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
}
```

... will return :

Song: Playlist1,Number of Songs: 3,Zanr: Genre2